# Recursive duplicate removal from a type list causes compiler out heap space error (VS2017)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, internal-compiler-error

I tried to strip down as much code as I could from my actual project. This is the minimal code required to reproduce this error.
It seems the compiler needs exponentially more space the more types are added to the base type list.

**Why is that?** and
**Any ideas how to work around this limitation?**

The code constructs a flattened type list from other type lists and types and removes duplicates to provide a unique id for each type registered in the list.

I need this code to work with at least 30-50 types in the type list. The purpose of the code is to provide a runtime type reflection system for explicitly listed types like in this example:

```
#include <tuple>

// Utils
// Type for concatenated tuples
template<typename... input_t> using tuple_cat_t = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<input_t>()...));

// Helper to check if a type is contained in a tuple already
template <typename T, typename Tuple> struct contains;
template <typename T, typename... Us> struct contains<T, std::tuple<Us...>> : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Us>...> {};
template< class T, class U > inline constexpr bool contains_v = contains<T, U>::value;

// Filter Code:
template <class Out, class In> struct filter_duplicates;

// Partial spezialization for the recursive deduction to end (when input tuple is empty)
template <class Out> struct filter_duplicates<Out /*finished filtered output tuple*/, std::tuple<> /*empty input tuple*/>
{
    using filtered_tuple_t = Out;

    // The filter function deduction ends here if the input tuple is empty (every element checked). In this case _In is the found filtered output tuple
    static constexpr Out& filter(Out&& _In) { return _In; }
};

/* Filter template that is used as long the input tuple is not empty. 
It builds the output tuple by recursively checking every element in the 
input tuple and deciding whether is can be added to the output tuple and 
then continuous deduction with the next input element until the 
filter_duplicates definition above matches. */
template <class... OutTypes, class InTest, class... InRest>
struct filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...>, std::tuple<InTest, InRest...>>
{
    // contained is true if the InTest element from the input tuple is contained in the output tuple already
    static constexpr bool contained = contains_v<InTest, std::tuple<OutTypes...>>;
    // depending on the condition above either add_t or rem_t is used (which adds InTest to the output tuple or not
    using add_t = filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes..., InTest>, std::tuple<InRest...>>;
    using rem_t = filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...        >, std::tuple<InRest...>>;
    // These types resolve to a tuple<...> with either added or remove InTest type
    using add_tuple_t = typename add_t::filtered_tuple_t;
    using rem_tuple_t = typename rem_t::filtered_tuple_t;
    // This type is the result of the check if InTest is contained, so its either add_tuple_t or rem_tuple_t
    using filtered_tuple_t = std::conditional_t<contained, rem_tuple_t, add_tuple_t>;
    // This type is the result of the check if InTest is contained, so its either the filter_duplicate type containing InTest in the OutTypes or not
    using filter_t = std::conditional_t<contained, rem_t, add_t>;

    // The function takes the unfiltered tuple instance and returns the filtered tuple instance (duplicate tuple entries are filtered)
    static constexpr auto filter(std::tuple<OutTypes..., InTest, InRest...>&& _In)
    {
        return filter_seq<contained>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(OutTypes)>{}, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(InRest) + 1 - contained>{}, std::move(_In));
    }

    // The input tuple for the next deduction step is built by getting all tuple elements except "InTest" in the case it is in the output list already
    template<size_t _Skip, size_t... TIndicesOut, size_t... TIndicesIn, class... In>
    static constexpr auto filter_seq(std::index_sequence<TIndicesOut...>, std::index_sequence<TIndicesIn...>, std::tuple<In...>&& _In)
    {
        return filter_t::filter(std::make_tuple(std::move(std::get<TIndicesOut>(_In))..., std::move(std::get<sizeof...(TIndicesOut) + _Skip + TIndicesIn>(_In))...));
    }
};
// Some declarations for easier use
template <class T> using no_duplicates_tuple_t = typename filter_duplicates<std::tuple<>, T>::filtered_tuple_t;
template <class T> using no_duplicates_filter = filter_duplicates<std::tuple<>, T>;
// Function to return a filtered tuple given an unfiltered tuple. It uses the filter type above to construct the new tuple with correct type
template<class... In> constexpr auto make_tuple_no_duplicates(std::tuple<In...>&& _In)
{
    return no_duplicates_filter<std::tuple<In...>>::filter(std::move(_In));
}

// Type info wrapper (In my project it contains functions like construct or copy and much more for the runtime type reflection)
struct IType {};
struct STypeUnknown : IType { using TType = void; };
template<typename T> struct SType : IType { using TType = T; };

// STypeList forward declation
template <typename...> struct STypeList;

// This type unwrappes a given STypeList into a flattened plain tuple, so it can be concatenated with other STypeLists or Types

// In case the given type is just a normal type, it is converted into a tuple with a single element: tuple<T> (so tuple_cat() can be used later)
template<typename T> struct SUnwrapTypeList
{
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<T>;
    tuple_type as_tuple;
    SUnwrapTypeList(T& _Value) : as_tuple{ _Value } {}
};
// In case the Type is a STypeList its filtered and flattened tuple is used
template<typename... TypeDefs> struct SUnwrapTypeList<STypeList<TypeDefs...>>
{
    using TypeList = STypeList<TypeDefs...>;
    using tuple_type = typename TypeList::TTupleDef;
    tuple_type as_tuple;
    SUnwrapTypeList(TypeList& _Value) : as_tuple(_Value.infos) {}
};

// The actual STypeList that can be constructed from other STypeList instances
template<typename... TypeDefs> struct STypeList
{
    // Defines the actual underlying flattened and filtered tuple<...>
    using TTupleDef = no_duplicates_tuple_t<tuple_cat_t<typename SUnwrapTypeList<TypeDefs>::tuple_type...>>;
    // Type count after flattening and filtering
    static constexpr size_t TypeCount() { return std::tuple_size<TTupleDef>::value; }
    // helper to get an index_sequence for the filtered flattened tuple
    static constexpr auto type_seq = std::make_index_sequence<TypeCount()>{};

    // All type infos given via the STypeList constructor, flattened and filtered
    TTupleDef infos;

    // This constructor is used in the example below. It can take arbitrary STypeLists or SType<XXX> lists and flattens and filteres them using the code above
    STypeList(TypeDefs... _Types) noexcept : STypeList(type_seq, std::tuple_cat(SUnwrapTypeList<TypeDefs>(_Types).as_tuple...)) {}
    STypeList(TTupleDef& _Types) noexcept : STypeList(type_seq, _Types) {}
    STypeList(STypeList&& _Move) noexcept : STypeList(type_seq, _Move.infos) {}
    STypeList(const STypeList& _Copy) noexcept : STypeList(type_seq, _Copy.infos) {}

private:
    // Final constructor initializing infos. TListIndices is the index_sequence for the filtered and flattened tuple, while TType is the unfiltered flattened tuple from the constructors above
    template <size_t... TListIndices, typename... TTypes>
    STypeList(std::index_sequence<TListIndices...>, std::tuple<TTypes...>&& _Types) noexcept
        : infos{ make_tuple_no_duplicates(std::move(_Types)) }
    { }

    // Final constructor initializing infos via copy
    template <size_t... TListIndices>
    STypeList(std::index_sequence<TListIndices...>, const TTupleDef& _Infos) noexcept
        : infos(_Infos)
    { }
};

// Test Code:
struct STestType1 { };
struct STestType2 { };

static inline auto TypeListBase = STypeList
(
    STypeUnknown()
    ,SType<bool>()
    ,SType<float>()
    ,SType<double>()
    ,SType<int>()
    ,SType<long>()
    ,SType<char>() //<- comment in to produce error
);

static inline auto TypeListA = STypeList
(
    TypeListBase
    ,SType<STestType1>()
);

static inline auto TypeListB = STypeList
(
    TypeListBase
    ,SType<STestType2>()
);

static inline auto TypeListAB = STypeList
(
    TypeListA,
    TypeListB
);

int main()
{

}
```

When trying to compile the output will be (using Visual Studio 2017, problem seems to occur in gcc and VS2019 as well):

```
1>------ Build started: Project: VsTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>VsTest.cpp
1>XXX\vstest.cpp(20): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space
1>Done building project "VsTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: "*I need this code to work with at least 30-50 types in the type list.*" I honestly would not expect any serious metaprogramming techniques to work on typelists of that size. That's just not a reasonable thing to expect of a compiler.

Comment: I can't solve it giving the compiler more space. Using like 30 types already uses like 20GB and ongoing with VS2019

Comment: When I remove the filtering code, it works with that many types. So something in the duplicate removal code makes the compiler burst

Comment: You can try learning/using Boost Hana to help with metaprogramming. It is designed to have better compilation performance than regular metaprogramming techniques. Not sure how well it works with VS, though.

Comment: I would like to avoid boost for several reasons. Also I am not sure if hana provides any simpler template meta code for a problem like this. Unless there is a more clever way to instantiate a filtered tuple. But I was not able to find a simpler solution. My current work around is to filter duplicates myself, not using nested lists. Which is very unfortunate

Comment: TBH just looking at the code I can't fault MSVC. My head overflows too.

Comment: I tried my best to give reasonable names, but for this minimal example I remove almost all comments. I think its not easy to make this code any simpler. It basically concatenates flattened type lists and then removes duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now... for something completely different...

What about avoiding the recursive sequence of `filter()` and `filter_seq()` calling using a variadic list of `bool` that say which element extract and which are duplicates?

I mean... given the same helper class `with_duplicate` in the other answer

```
template <typename, typename>
struct with_duplicate : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename OTuple, typename IT0, typename ... ITs>
struct with_duplicate<OTuple, std::tuple<IT0, ITs...>>
   : public contains<IT0, OTuple>
 { };
```

I propose a `filter_duplicate` declaration a little more complicated

```
template <typename Out, typename In,
          typename = std::integer_sequence<bool>,
          typename = std::index_sequence<>,
          bool = with_duplicate<Out, In>::value>
struct filter_duplicates;
```

Now the two recursion cases, cases "is in list" and "isn't in list", that simply inherit from the old `filter_t` types

```
template <typename... OutTypes, typename InTest, typename... InRest,
          typename Is, bool ... Bs>
struct filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...>,
                         std::tuple<InTest, InRest...>,
                         std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs...>,
                         Is, true>
   : public filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...>,
                              std::tuple<InRest...>,
                              std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs..., true>,
                              std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Bs)+1u>>
 { };

template <typename... OutTypes, typename InTest, typename... InRest,
          typename Is, bool ... Bs>
struct filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...>,
                         std::tuple<InTest, InRest...>,
                         std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs...>,
                         Is, false>
   : public filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes..., InTest>,
                              std::tuple<InRest...>,
                              std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs..., false>,
                              std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Bs)+1u>>
 { };
```

Now the complex part is the ground case that receive a variadic list of `bool`, one for every type in the original tuple, `Bs...`, where `true` is "duplicate type" and `false` is "no duplicate type"

```
// ground case
template <typename Out, bool ... Bs, std::size_t ... Is>
struct filter_duplicates<Out, std::tuple<>,
                         std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs...>,
                         std::index_sequence<Is...>, false>
 {
   using filtered_tuple_t = Out;

   template <bool B, std::size_t I, typename Tpl>
   static constexpr auto getTplCond (Tpl && t)
    {
      if constexpr ( B ) // duplicate
         return std::tuple<>{};
      else // not duplicate
         return std::tuple{std::get<I>(t)};
    }

   template <typename ... Ts>
   static constexpr std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Bs), Out>
       filter (std::tuple<Ts...> && _In)
    { return std::tuple_cat( getTplCond<Bs, Is>(_In)... ); }
 };
```

This way you call a single `filter()` method that isn't recursive but is recursively inherited.

Also `filtered_type_t` is recursively inherited.

Comment: This is really clever! Did this perform better in your tests?

Comment: @ecreif - almost the same, from the point of view of compilation time; but I suppose that avoids a lot of recursive function calls (but consider that I'm not an expert of compilers).

Comment: yes I assumed that this might have better runtime performance. But I think the compiler might be able to resolve the whole recursion tree into one flat call. But I didn't check that. Anyways in my case this is only called once at startup. So runtime is not too big an issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is that your `filter_duplicate`, the recursive specialization, ever follows both cases: the case the `InTest` is in the `OutTypes...` list and the case it isn't.

This force the compiler to follows a lot of dead cases.

Suggestion: split the recursive specialization in two recursive specializations: the version "is in list" and the "isn't in list" one.

I suggest an additional helper template

```
template <typename, typename>
struct with_duplicate : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename OTuple, typename IT0, typename ... ITs>
struct with_duplicate<OTuple, std::tuple<IT0, ITs...>>
   : public contains<IT0, OTuple>
 { };
```

Now the `filter_duplicates` declaration, with an additional template defaulted parameter (based on `with_duplicate`)

```
template <typename Out, typename In, bool = with_duplicate<Out, In>::value>
struct filter_duplicates;
```

The ground case remain almost the same (just added the third template parameter)

```
// ground case
template <typename Out>
struct filter_duplicates<Out, std::tuple<>, false>
 {
   using filtered_tuple_t = Out;
   static constexpr Out& filter(Out&& _In) { return _In; }
 };
```

Now the recursive case "is in list"

```
// with duplicate case
template <typename... OutTypes, typename InTest, typename... InRest>
struct filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...>,
                         std::tuple<InTest, InRest...>,
                         true>
 {
   using filter_t = filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...>,
                                      std::tuple<InRest...>>;

   using filtered_tuple_t = typename filter_t::filtered_tuple_t;

   static constexpr auto
      filter (std::tuple<OutTypes..., InTest, InRest...>&& _In)
    { return filter_seq(
          std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(OutTypes)>{},
          std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(InRest)>{},
          std::move(_In)); }

   template <std::size_t... TIndicesOut,
             std::size_t... TIndicesIn, typename... In>
   static constexpr auto filter_seq (std::index_sequence<TIndicesOut...>,
                                     std::index_sequence<TIndicesIn...>,
                                     std::tuple<In...>&& _In)
    { return filter_t::filter(std::make_tuple(
             std::move(std::get<TIndicesOut>(_In))...,
             std::move(std::get<sizeof...(TIndicesOut) + 1u + TIndicesIn>(_In))...)); }
 };
```

and the recursive case "isn't in list"

```
// without duplicate case
template <typename... OutTypes, typename InTest, typename... InRest>
struct filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes...>,
                         std::tuple<InTest, InRest...>,
                         false>
 {
   using filter_t = filter_duplicates<std::tuple<OutTypes..., InTest>,
                                      std::tuple<InRest...>>;

   using filtered_tuple_t = typename filter_t::filtered_tuple_t;

   static constexpr auto
      filter (std::tuple<OutTypes..., InTest, InRest...>&& _In)
    { return filter_seq(
          std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(OutTypes)>{},
          std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(InRest) + 1u>{},
          std::move(_In)); }

   template <std::size_t... TIndicesOut,
             std::size_t... TIndicesIn, typename... In>
   static constexpr auto filter_seq (std::index_sequence<TIndicesOut...>,
                                     std::index_sequence<TIndicesIn...>,
                                     std::tuple<In...>&& _In)
    { return filter_t::filter(std::make_tuple(
             std::move(std::get<TIndicesOut>(_In))...,
             std::move(std::get<sizeof...(TIndicesOut) + TIndicesIn>(_In))...)); }
 };
```

Not sure all indexes in `filter()` and `filter_seq()` methods are correct (check yourself) but, this way, the compiler should avoid a lot of unuseful implementations.

In my Linux platform, splitting the recursive specialization, I've reduced the compilation time (clang++ and g++, in sequence) from 51",1 to 1",6. No exact data abut memory consumption but I can say that is greatly reduced.

Comment: This seems to work and greatly reduces compile time too. Thank you so much! You are my hero

Comment: I wish the compilers would show more how they internally deduce types like these. So debugging wouldn't be like digging in the dark